# Java Beginner here, I'm trying to figure out how to check whether a scanner input is an integer or not

Tags: java

I have this code I'm working on for a class but I can't seem to figure out how to go about it using a try-catch. I'm using a do-while loop to repeat the input process in the case that the input doesn't turn out to be an integer. I've been told to just get my hands dirty and try out everything, so I did. It's wacky I know. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


   System.out.println("This program gets ten numbers from the user, and\n" +
    "computes and displays the average.");

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   do {

    System.out.println("Please enter integer 1");

    int integer1 = input.nextInt();
    String intStr1 = Integer.toString(integer1);

    try {

     int myInt = Integer.parseInt(intStr1);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

     System.out.println("Please enter a proper integer");

     Boolean intCheck = true;

    }

   } while (intCheck == true);
```

Comment: **Read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), to see the list of available methods, and you will find [`hasNextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) --- With correct use of `hasXxx()` calls, you'll won't need `try-catch` at all for this.

Comment: If nextInt() didn't throw an exception, then it read an integer.

Answer (score 0):

for the statement `int integer1 = input.nextInt();` if integer is not entered by the user, program will throw `InputMismatchException`. You can catch that and do further computation. 
**So if the exception is thrown it is not an integer and if not it is an integer.**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


   System.out.println("This program gets ten numbers from the user, and\n" +
    "computes and displays the average.");

   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   do {

    System.out.println("Please enter integer 1");


    String intStr1=input.nextLine();

    try {

     int myInt = Integer.parseInt(intStr1);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

     System.out.println("Please enter a proper integer");

     Boolean intCheck = true;

    }

   } while (intCheck == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

just replace the two lines

```
 int integer1 = input.nextInt(); and
 String intStr1 = Integer.toString(integer1);
```

with

```
 String intStr1 = input.nextLine();
```

what you have originally done is to scan for an integer (which will throw an exception if it is not). if it is an error, then you need to flush the buffer to take in a new user input.

what you can do instead is to read the user input as a whole line (until an ENTER is detected), then try to do the conversion.

other things you can consider is to call intStr1.trim() to remove spaces before and at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a **try/catch** construct to carry out this task. Just use the [Scanner#nextLine()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_nextline.htm) method and validate the input with the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method to ensure the input was in fact a string representation of numerical digits.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String ls = System.lineSeparator();
int intsSum = 0;
System.out.println("This program gets ten numbers from the User and"
            + ls + "computes and displays the average (q to quit)." + ls);

int count = 0;
do {
    count++;
    System.out.print("Please enter Integer value #" + count + ": --> ");
    String userInput = input.nextLine();  // Get User Input
    if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        System.out.println("Bye Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // Does the input consist of all numerical digits? 
    if (!userInput.matches("\\d+")) {
        // NO...
        System.out.println("Invalid Input! Please enter a proper integer value!" + ls);
        count--;
        continue;
    }
    intsSum += Integer.parseInt(userInput);
} while (count < 10);
System.out.println(ls + "The average value for the 10 numbers entered is: " + (intsSum / 10));
```

The [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx) used with the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method (`"\\d+"`) basically means ***does the string contain all numerical digits***. So with the **if** statement, we are asking: *if the input string **does not** match all numerical digits then inform user of invalid input*.